# pd.read_csv a text file of 750 MB

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I read a text file of 750 MB using `pd.read_csv`, the top 5 rows in the text have fewer fields than the rest of the rows. What I have done is:

```
ICP_CTCT_TRADER_MEP=pd.read_csv('EDA_CTCT_TRADER_MEP.txt', sep=',', header=None, skiprows=5, encoding='ISO-8859-1',engine='python')
```

Tthe top 5 rows:

```
0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   ... 12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21
DET 0000000001CP630 METERSUMMARY    MET-10748517    17/08/2013  20/08/2013 17:11:28 NGCM    NGCM20130817MM010100000.txt Active  NaN NaN NaN NaN NGCM    1   ... N   Y   2   N   NaN None    None    None    None    None
METERINSTALL    MET-10748517    17/08/2013  20/08/2013 17:11:28 NGCM    NGCM20130817MM010100000.txt Active  NaN NaN NaN NaN 1   1   ... HHR F   21/10/2011  21/10/2026  N   X   03/05/2023  N145361 90  NaN
METERCOMP   MET-10748517    17/08/2013  20/08/2013 17:11:28 NGCM    NGCM20130817MM010100000.txt Active  NaN NaN NaN NaN 1   211313791   ... Y   1   1   NGCS    NaN None    None    None    None    None
METERCHANNEL    MET-10748517    17/08/2013  20/08/2013 17:11:28 NGCM    NGCM20130817MM010100000.txt Active  NaN NaN NaN NaN 1   211313791   ... UN  24  kWh X   C   Y   NaN None    None    None
17/08/2013  20/08/2013 17:11:28 NGCM    NGCM20130817MM010100000.txt Active  NaN NaN NaN NaN 1   211313791   ... CN  17  kWh X   C   Y   NaN None    None    None
```

The auto headers is from the sixth columns, no header for the first 5 columns. My solution is to export it to .csv and import it back to get the proper header for each columns like below

```
ICP_CTCT_TRADER_MEP=ICP_CTCT_TRADER_MEP.dropna(thresh=200000, axis='columns') # to remove the NaN Columns
ICP_CTCT_TRADER_MEP.to_csv('ICP_CTCT_TRADER_MEP.csv') # to export it to a .csv file
ICP_CTCT_TRADER_MEP_1=pd.read_csv('ICP_CTCT_TRADER_MEP.csv') #to import it back again
```

My question is: is there a better way to do it? My way above takes long time, and it's sometimes not working, failing with a memory error.

Comment: Where is the header? Row 0 or row 6 in the file? And are you just going to drop the first 5 rows?

Comment: why to export to file and read it again ? You should get the same data as befor saving.

Comment: okay, if I am getting it right..you're trying to import a text file into a dataframe and then clean it and export it into a csv and then again import it into a dataframe so you get data in their revelent columns?

Comment: to export and re import it again, so i can have a proper headers for each columns.

Comment: i am new here, don't know how to answer the questions above. hope this is right way to do it.
the reason i export and read it again is because the first read didn't give me a proper header for each columns. and i don't know how to split the dataframe based on the first import. so read it again to obtain the proper headers for each column, after that i can rename the columns, and select the columns and rows to do analysis

Comment: i have solved my problem by naming the columns while importing:
names=['VAR_1','VAR_2','VAR_3','VAR_4','VAR_5','VAR_6','VAR_7','VAR_8','VAR_9','VAR_10','VAR_11','VAR_12','VAR_13','VAR_14','VAR_15','VAR_16','VAR_17','VAR_18','VAR_19','VAR_20','VAR_21','VAR_22','VAR_23','VAR_24','VAR_25','VAR_26','VAR_27']
ICP_CTCT_TRADER_MEP=pd.read_csv('EDA_CTCT_TRADER_MEP.txt', sep=',', header=None, skiprows=6,names=names, encoding='ISO-8859-1',engine='python')
ICP_CTCT_TRADER_MEP.shape